# Displaying 3d space

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to display my work 3d space which was made in blender to a website where anyone can walkthrough my space with a link on any devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try blend4web.
You will probably have to code things by yourself since web and 3D are two different domains.

https://www.blend4web.com/en/

On example on how to use it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dtmzyv-sTvs